# jQuery Validation script doesn't work, at all

Tags: jquery, validation

So I'm creating a contact form, and I'm trying to create a validation script, and it doesn't work at all, it doesn't even show errors. It just goes to default validation.

I have looked in the resources, and the JS file is loaded on the page but is just doesn't work...?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("answercheck", function(e, t) {
    return this.optional(t) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(e)
}, "Please type the correct answer"), $(function() {
    $("#contact").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: !0,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: !0,
                email: !0
            },
            message: {
                required: !0
            },
            answer: {
                required: !0,
                answercheck: !0
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter a name",
                minlength: "Your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter an email"
            },
            message: {
                required: "Please enter a message",
                minlength: "Please enter a longer message"
            },
            answer: {
                required: "Incorrect"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"process.php",
                success: function() {
                    $('#contact :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#contact').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                        $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                        $('#success').fadeIn();
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#contact').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                        $('#error').fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xmj590nj/1/ ?

Comment: Ok so for some reason the jsFidddle works, but not [the webpage](http://webyo.com.au/contact-us.html)

Comment: You have an error in the console: 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sticky is not a function' that block other scripts execution

Comment: @IrvinDominin oh, that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the console you'll see an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sticky is not a function

that error block other scripts execution and the validation too.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in an other code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#links').ReSmenu({
    maxWidth: 750
  });
  $("#header2").sticky({  //<--- here is the error thrown
    className: 'stuck'
  });
});
```

in the console (`F12`) you can see the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sticky is not a function